# Select2 difficult to use on Android phone, due to predictive text

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using the latest version of select2 with ajax on a mobile webapp. It is a great plug in but very difficult to use on a Galaxy Edge phone.

It is difficult to select the second or third entry listed in the search results of the drop down.

I have noticed though that turning predictive text on the phone off, it works very well.

I have tried adding this on my select input:

`autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false"`

and although I can see it flow through to the select2 input box after render, it does not disable predictive text / autocomplete as desired.

Has anybody solved this issue as I cannot find a direct reference to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have difficulties selecting items from the `select2` (as described [here](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1541) because of the popping of virtual keyboard), try this after you initialize the `select2`:

```
  jQuery('.select2-search input').prop('readonly', true);
```

Or, try this workaround:

```
jQuery(document).on('touchend', function(){
jQuery(".select2-search, .select2-focusser").remove();
})
```

This will prevent keyboard from showing on multiple select

Comment: Hi @bodi0, thanks for the reply. It made no difference. Once i turn off predictive text it work perfectly, other wise it is not possible to select.